# How to serve a Nodejs & Express app using Phusion Passanger

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, forever

I have a node & express app that is currently hosted on a shared hosting. I would like to run and manage the app using Phusion Passenger. My hosting account supports nodejs applications managed by Passenger which i have never used before.

[image]

The server code generated when setting up the Node app is the basic server setup as below.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
    version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
    response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen();
```

I would like to replace this with the code below that has elements of express that i am using to serve my API routes.

```
//import modules
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    cors = require('cors');
    path = require('path');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//import database connection from dbconnect.js file
var mysql = require('./dbconnect/dbconnect');

//Parse as urlencoded and json.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//adding middleware - cors
app.use(cors());

//Http logger
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Uncomment for production
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Point static path to public
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//import routes from /routes/routes.js
var user = require('./routes/Users');  
    route = require('./routes/route');
    router = require('./router/router');
//adding routes
app.use('/api', user, route, router);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('/*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});

app.use(function (req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.listen(port, function() {console.log('Server started at http://localhost:'+port+'/');});
```

but i get the error:

[image]

I am currently running my server script on the shared server using **Forever**, which is working fine but that hasn't been efficient, so i would like to switch to using Passenger.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to set your `NODE_ENV=development` and then look at your page again? It will likely output a lot more information, why it throws the Error.

With the error information, we can have a better look at what might be wrong.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with your routes and it not finding the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to do `npm install` to get your dependencies. I had the same problem but that was it

Answer (score 0):

I will add this answer to the pool. This looks familliar to the DirectAdmin panel I have been using. I you press the link "Technical details..." they will refer to the Passenger log file. In it you will find more details about what is causing the error when you start your expressjs server. BUT to be able to find it I first had to specify the log file path when setting up the node JS module. Without it the log file will never be created: [image]